# iOS app rejected by Apple after test device fails SMS based user authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, core-telephony

I have an iOS app that is intended for use on iPhone devices only.

The `Target Device Families` build setting is set to `iPhone`.

The `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` build setting includes `telephony`, a capability not available with iPads.

Apple rejects the app because, during multi-factor authentication, their iPad is not capable of sending/receiving SMS text messages.

Apple documentation states that

> At runtime, iOS cannot launch your application unless the declared capabilities are present on the device. Further, the App Store requires this information so that it can generate a list of requirements for user devices and prevent users from downloading applications that they cannot run.

My interpretation of this is that an iPad cannot launch my application because Telephony capabilities are not present on the device.

***My Questions***

1. Is `telephony` truly a capability that renders iPads unusable or not?
2. Short of developing an entire demo version of the app just for the review process, what strategy exists to get approval for any SMS-based feature an app may have?

I understand the last question is a bit opinion based, but I think an answer for it could help others dodge this issue when developing SMS-based features.

Perhaps the only viable solution is to make a demo version just for them.

Answer (score 2):

I checked WhatsApp (which also needs SMS auth), and it is not available on iPad App Store.
In its `Info.plist` it has the following iPhone-related keys:

```
   <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
   <array>
      <string>iPhoneOS</string>
   </array>
   <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
   <dict>
      <key>telephony</key>
      <true/>
   </dict>
   <key>DTPlatformName</key>
   <string>iphoneos</string>
   <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
   <true/>
   <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
   <array>
      <integer>1</integer>
   </array>
```

You may try to add them and check the review process again.

Comment: Very nice investigating, thank you! I will make this attempt ASAP, looks promising. Will mark as accepted when I hear back (good news hopefully) from Apple. Thanks again.